How to set a quota on Logical Disk Space (logicalused) in ZFS?
I am currently using ZFS and need to set a quota on the logical disk space (logicalused) rather than the physical disk space used after compression. The quota and refquota properties in ZFS set a limit based on the physical space, not on the logical space.
For example, I have dataset with quota and refquota set to 120M.
When I try to fill it with the files, I get result:
# zfs list -o name,quota,used,logicalused,compressratio,referenced,logicalreferenced storage/datatest
NAME                      QUOTA   USED  LUSED  RATIO     REFER  LREFER
storage/datatest           120M   120M   147M  1.68x      120M    147M

But I want to get something like that:
NAME                      QUOTA   USED  LUSED  RATIO     REFER  LREFER
storage/datatest           120M    XXX   120M  1.68x       XXX    120M

Is there a way to set a quota in ZFS that limits the amount of logical space used, i.e. the space used before any compression or deduplication?
Thank you in advance for any insights or suggestions!
